# How to use a string in order to call and assign a value which is already defined ? (In VBA)

Tags: vba, variable-assignment

I have an integer variable named `MaxChart` and it has already a value of 1024. Now i want to call this value with a string variable with the same name `MaxChart` and assign a new value to that.

How do I go about this ?

```
For i = 1 To 20

    A = "MaxChart"& Cstr(i)

Next i
```

and then to use `A` as the name of the variable and assign a new value to it!

This Function exist in `MATLAB` with name of `assignin`:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html

I don't know how to use it in VBA?

Comment: So `"MaxChart" = 1024`? - There is no direct equivalent, you would use an `array(numeric_index) =` or a `collection(key_name) =`

Answer (score 1):

Assigning variable names at runtime is not possible in VBA. If you really need to work with those variable names you can use a dictionary though.

First you have to make a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime:
"Extras - References" => Check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

After that you can use a dictionary and reference the keys like this:

```
Sub Main()

    Set MaxChartDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Create the entries with the appropriate keyname => change the second "i" 
    'to whatever value you would like
    For i = 1 To 20
        MaxChartDict.Add "MaxChart" & i, i
    Next

    'Get the values for the key "MaxChart3" and "MaxChart14"
    MsgBox (MaxChartDict("MaxChart3"))
    MsgBox (MaxChartDict("MaxChart14"))

    'Change the value for key "MaxChart3"
    MaxChartDict("MaxChart3") = "foobar"
    MsgBox (MaxChartDict("MaxChart3"))

    Set MaxChartDict = Nothing

End Sub
```